# How to check nodejs socket is exists on another nodejs server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I wants to setup a nodejs chat app on two servers, but my concern is that will node check that the user who wants to send messages on the socket is connected on different socket.

- suppose nodejs1 is on server1 and listing on 3001 and nodejs2 is on server2 listing on 3002
- user 1 is connected to 3001 and user 2 is connected to 3002
- user 1 wants to send a message to user 2
- user 1 and user 2 socket is stored on db

Is this communication can be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

check it out if https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session can work out for you as if you will use socket.io

Socket.io is doing multiple requests to perform handshake and establish connection with a client. With a cluster those requests may arrive to different workers, which will break handshake protocol.

Sticky-sessions module is balancing requests using their IP address. Thus client will always connect to same worker server, and socket.io will work as expected, but on multiple processes!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i wants to setup on different machine, how one socket is communicate with other, I want to balancing load of node js thats why

Comment: also checkout this article, will help you..http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/load-balancing-node-js/

Comment: sorry for lot of comments but this article will clear out answer..http://cjihrig.com/blog/scaling-node-js-applications/